# SqlException was unhandled

Tags: c#, sql, linq

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS)
>   remove procedure call (RPC) protocol
>   stream is incorrect.  Parameter 9
>   ("@p6"): The supplied value is not a
>   valid instance of data type float. 
>   Check the source data for invalid
>   values.  An example of an invalid
>   value is data of numeric type with
>   scale greater than precision.

I'm getting this strange error on a DB submit, what could be causing this?

Comment: Does "The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float" give you enough hint to find the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may seem a little obvious, but have you tried following the exception message and taking a look at the value in `Parameter 9 ("@p6")`? Make sure it's

> a valid instance of data type float